How to lock the always on top subinterface when run a operator

Open a always on top subinterface


Run a operator modal



import bpy

class MyOps(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_ops"
    bl_label = "object my ops"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'BLOCKING'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == "ESC":
            return {"CANCELLED"}
        if event.value == "PRESS":
            print("modal is running... ESC to cancel")
        # some jobs..
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyOps)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyOps)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


when the operator run, the main window and the top window will lock since BLOCKING in bl_options. It works fine but when you deactivate the window (click on the desktop), the user can control the on top window again. If the user can control the top window and modify the blend data while the operator is running, it will result bugs, so how to lock all on top subinterface while the operator is running?


Do you want the modal to continue running if the user clicks outside the window? Like is it okay if you just cancel the modal if the user clicks outside the main window? Or do you want to keep it running and maintain the blocked state?

There are other ways to deactivate the window except "click", I need the modal keep running.

You can tell if they've clicked out of the window on the desktop cause the modal sends a "WINDOW_DEACTIVATE" event. So you could maybe store a boolean to check if they've clicked out by checking for that event, and then any "LEFT_MOUSE" events after that you can check to see if the window was ever deactivated with that bool and process those following events differently? It seems like a weird edge case.

Internal bug confirmed, temporary solution for blender 4.2:
The idea is when you start your modal, run a empty modal to all subwindow.
And remove them when finished.
import bpy, weakref

class Empty(Operator):
    __slots__ = '__weakref__'

    bl_idname = "wm.empty"
    bl_label = "Empty modal for blocking"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    fin_request = False
    modals = weakref.WeakValueDictionary() # items will automatically remove when modal finished

    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        Empty.modals[context.window] = self
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if Empty.fin_request is True:
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

# remember register the class

def block_all_subwindows():
    Empty.fin_request = False
    windows = bpy.context.window_manager.windows
    if len(windows) == 1: return

    for w in windows:
        if hasattr(w.screen, "name") and w.screen.name == "temp":
            if w in Empty.modals:
                continue
            with bpy.context.temp_override(window=w):
                bpy.ops.wm.empty()
            continue

        if w.parent == None:
            continue

        if w in Empty.modals:
            continue

        with bpy.context.temp_override(window=w):
            bpy.ops.wm.empty()

def unblock_all_subwindows():
    Empty.fin_request = True

